# Sampling 1 item from groups of correlated values and combining the statistics

Tags: uniform-distribution, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, subsampling

We have a dataset consisting of several groups of observations:

| Group | Object | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gr_1 | Ob_1 | V_1 |
| Gr_1 | Ob_2 | V_2 |
| Gr_2 | Ob_3 | V_3 |
| ... | ... | ... |

All values lie in the interval [0,1].
In each of the groups Gr_i the values are likely to be rather close to each other, because they usually come from similar objects. There are also certain correlations between values in distinct groups.

In the discipline studying these objects there is a common division into the categories of "narrow" and "broad", depending on the value V_i being small (close to 0) or large (close to 1). However, the data does not seem to support such a division, because the values seem to fill the whole interval [0,1] rather evenly. How can one try to make this rigorous?

The best I could come up with is the following: take 1 value from each group and look at the resulting sample. One can use one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for the uniform distribution - if we take 1000 such samples and consider the KS test p-values as a sample from a random variable, we get the mean of 0.49 and the standard deviation of 0.15. This looks like a reasonable expression of the idea that the distinction into "narrow" and "broad" is not very pronounced. However, it would be even better to combine these p-values (or the initial KS-statistics) into a single value. Were these samples we get independent, one could use Fisher's method, but they are not, so some variant of Fisher's method should be used, but I'm having troubles figuring out which one would work best (also, there are apparently many pitfalls there, so should be very careful). Any ideas or alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fail to grasp the objective and need clarification of the question. Are you trying to demonstrate a point that the sample shows a special pattern of uniformly distributed values unlike both narrow and broad categories commonly observed in some discipline? Then just display an empirical distribution plot of values. It does not seem that any particular hypotheses must be tested to illustrate this sample property. Does the disciplinary theory require that values follow a certain non-uniform distribution? Is the requirement about the marginal distribution (without considering `Group` effects) or conditional distribution (when `Group` effects are accounted for)?

If you must tell the story using p values, you may have to build a mixed-effect model because I am not aware of any repeated-measurement counterpart of KS test. Since the response `Value` is between zero and one, you can use

- Fractional models with random or fixed effects of `Group`, if probability mass at zero and one are substantial. See Stata tutorial on fractional response https://www.stata.com/features/overview/fractional-outcome-models. Michael Clark (2019) Fractional Regression: A quick primer regarding data between zero and one, including zero and one https://m-clark.github.io/posts/2019-08-20-fractional-regression/. Papke, L. E., & Wooldridge, J. M. (2008). Panel data methods for fractional response variables with an application to test pass rates. Journal of Econometrics, 145(1), 121–133. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jeconom.2008.05.009.
- Beta regression with `betareg()` or `glmmTMB()` with random or effects of `Group`, if no zero or one are observed.
- Transform value onto the entire real axis, such as `qnorm(Value)` so you can model the response as a normally distributed variable. Then you can use `nlme::lme()` and `lme4::lmer()` to model linear models with longitudinal data and random or fixed effects of `Group`. That `Value` is uniformly distributed is equivalent to that `qnorm(Value)` is normally distributed.

Comment: This http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers shows how to accept one's answer.

Comment: I think this is a good answer. I would add that testing the null hypothesis that the group means are uniform' is not a good statistical objective if all we want to do is show that the groups are not clustered.

Comment: I concur that not all analyses require a _p_ value. Descriptive statistics and illustration are also important tools.